# Integral and MacLaurin polynomial problem

Tags: integration, derivatives, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I can't seem to get this problem:
[image: problem]
So far I obtained the polynomial:

[image: polynomial]

But it is wrong.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

We have that $$\sin(t) = t-\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}+\ldots$$

Substitute $3t^2$ in for $t$ in the above equation, and evaluate the integral.

Comment: I don't know what the integral gives. I you could tell me what it is I will be able to do the rest @Hossmeister

Comment: $\int at^ndt=\frac {a}{n+1}t^{n+1} $

Answer (score 1):

If you do what Hossmeister suggested in his/her answer, you have
$$\sin(3t^2)=3 t^2-\frac{9 }{2}t^6+O\left(t^{10}\right)$$ so
$$\int \sin(3t^2)\,dt=t^3-\frac{9 t^7}{14}+O\left(t^{11}\right)$$
$$\int_0^x \sin(3t^2)\,dt=x^3-\frac{9 }{14}x^7$$